# Removing cluster node from always on cluster

Tags: database, sql-server, cluster, database-administration, sql-server-2012

I have an `alwaysOn` configuration for SqlServer 2012 that is installed in two node windows cluster.

We had a disk failure on the second node, and there is no way to recover it, so I should run a new installation on that node.

My question is:

if I never evict the failed node from the cluster to run the installation will have an effect on the running node ?

During installation of the second node only one node will be remaining on the cluster, is it OK ?

Answer (score 0):

I would evict the failing node, and adding a new one later on.

> During installation of the second node only one node will be remaining
>   on the cluster, is it OK ?

No that is not ok, and you will need to [start the clustering service in single mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/force-a-wsfc-cluster-to-start-without-a-quorum?view=sql-server-2017#PowerShellProcedure) using the following commands in powershell - run it as administrator - as you can see on the picture below:

```
Import-ModuleFailoverClusters
$node="SQLPROD2"
#Stop-ClusterNode -Name $node  

Start-ClusterNode-Name$node-FixQuorum

(Get-ClusterNode$node).NodeWeight =1

$nodes=Get-ClusterNode-Cluster$node
$nodes|Format-Table-propertyNodeName,State,NodeWeight
```

[image]

I basically had this situation in one of my clusters:
[image]

and Now I have this:

[image]

More details, and worth checking it out:

[Force a WSFC Cluster to Start Without a Quorum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/force-a-wsfc-cluster-to-start-without-a-quorum?view=sql-server-2017#PowerShellProcedure)